# Stop comment box appearing when using a facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I want to stop the comment box from appearing when a user likes something on my page.

Is this possible?

I'm using

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=153692861385098&amp;xfbml=1">
</script>
<fb:like href='http://www.domain.com/path/to/page.html' 
    send="true" layout="button_count" width="0" show_faces="false" font="">
</fb:like>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to do the same. It's not pefect, but the only way I've found to work thus far is to use the following CSS:

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget iframe.fb_ltr {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4871240/601299