# How to don't show facebook comment after like pressed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

So, when I click Like button I see the form to add some comment. I want to hide or prevent displaying this form. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

See this [Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up)

Basically you just need to modify the css and hide the comment box after facebook like.

Comment: That link is from 2010,  and if you have worked with facebook you know that what is a fix this year is probably depricated this year.