# Avoid post popup when clicking facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I have a page tab app for a client, and they want the fan gate to include the FB like button on the middle of the page in addition to the standard FB like button at the top right of the page tab frame. I've added the like button and it works fine. When the user clicks like, however, I want to redirect them to the main landing page.

I've subscribed to the edge.create event and everything works fine, but when you click the Like button, it pops up a comment box for you to share something on your wall. Even though this doesn't stop the redirect, it is an unnecessary distraction that I'd like to avoid. What are my options?

Can I somehow detect when that box is closed and then perform the redirect? Can I disable it entirely?

Comment: This has been resolved here (well, a workaround was found) http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312545/204033