# Google +1 Button - how to disable the pop up?

Tags: google-plus

I'd like to disable the box that appear when the user hover +1 button I've placed on my site. Also I'd like to disable the box that pops out when the action is made.

Is this possible to do? I can't find any details in the documentation.

Very similar question: [Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up)

Comment: There are multiple things that pop up, which are you referring to?
1) The tooltip "Recommend this...."
2) The site recommendations
3) The share box that pops up on CLICK not hover.

Comment: Ideally hide every popup.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the hover bubble is a feature of the +1 button, as it provides a user with additional information about what they are recommending.  At this time, it is not possible to remove them.  But you can feel free to make the feature request in our Issue Tracker, which you can find at http://developers.google.com/+/support.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to know the proper answer to this! Their data-recommendations="false" attribute currently does nothing. The best I have currently found is a CSS solution to hide the table that is displayed on hover:

```
table.gc-bubbleDefault.pls-container {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: FYI: The recommendations are additional information that appear within the tooltip, they do not turn off the tooltip in its entirety. The recommendations are only populated when Google is able to suggest other content on your site that might be relevant to the user based on a variety of factors. My guess is that your not seeing any difference is more that Google isn't able to recommend other content rather than being a problem with the attribute or behavior.