# refresh div containing facebook like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like, xfbml

My like button code goes as follows:

```
<div class="like-btn">                                                                       

<fb:like href="http://www.example-url.com" layout="box_count" show_faces="true" width="450" action="like" colorscheme="light" ></fb:like>

</div>
```

My problem is that, I do not want the comment box to be displayed after clicking like. I'm using XFBML version of Like Button for tracking purpose, so comment box is inevitable.
I have multiple like buttons in the page with variable href's.
I have read all the questions/solutions regarding removing the comment box in this scenario, but none of them work. I'm hoping that Refreshing the contents of `<div class="like-btn">` would help.

Could someone please help me figure out how I should tackle this problem?

Here is my attempt so far:

```
//copying content of the div since the href is retrieved via php and is variable
var content = $('.like-btn').html();
$('.like-btn').empty();
$('.like-btn').html(content);
```

## UPDATE

The approach shown in the accepted answer works perfectly for the default like button (XFBML/HTML5) but not for the `box-count` styled.

Comment: What's the resulting html when you click on it?

Comment: It removes the contents of .like-btn , but when I append the content there is no visible change.

Comment: that's because some Javascript parses and retrieves this <fb tag and applies it actions on it. in itself, <fb> doesn't mean anything to HTML, so you can't just add it to html. you really need to go down the CSS way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you are currently using it, try adding this to the page:

```
<style type="text/css">
.like-btn {
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

If that doesn't work, use the HTML5 Code for displaying the FB Like Button instead, something like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<style type="text/css">
.fb-like{
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-send="true"></div>
```

We set the height of `.fb-like` to `25 pixels` and `overflow: hidden`, which will prevent the comment box from popping up completely!

You can see it working here:  http://devs.dream-portal.net/dp11/index.php

## UPDATED

For the box-count style, you can use the iframe version for the box-count and no comment box gets displayed (atleast not to me):

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Freference%2Fplugins%2Flike&amp;width=450&amp;height=65&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=box_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;send=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:65px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

## RE-UPDATED

You can also review the Top Answer on this stackoverflow question here with 114 up votes:  [Facebook Like Button - how to disable Comment pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up)

Try that and maybe it will work... not sure.

Comment: I think vineetrok still needs the like button just not the resulting comment box

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but doing display:none will simply hide it. I need to refresh it

Comment: maybe try `.remove` instead of `.empty()`  Updated answer to remove it and than put it back into the parent element.  If you need to give it a class and an element within it, than you just need to redefine the class and element before you put content in it.

Comment: Updated answer with even more ways to try...  One of these approaches has to work.

Comment: I tried both answers, but sadly, the comment box appears atleast for a second, which is something I do not want.  I have to completely remove it. I do not know whether I should still accept an answer or not :-/

Comment: Updated answer - Please use HTML 5 code for the FB Like Button instead.  You can see it working here:  http://devs.dream-portal.net/dp11/index.php

Comment: You might be able to do it with just the simple `<style>` tag edit that I provided above, using the, current, XFBML version.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Actually its my bad, I didn't explicitly mention in the question that type of like button is `box-count`. sorry for that. Thus, I tried to use the above code with increased height, but the like button gets hidden by the comment box.

Comment: Well, I don't know than.  To be honest, it doesn't make sense for FB to even show it since it hides after clicking it.  I don't even understand the point of it, since you can't even type into it anyways...  Just another annoying fb thing IMO.

Comment: Use the `iframe` version to get rid of the comment box.

Comment: @SolomonClosson Thanks for your answer, but yeah,on the default button your approach will work totally as seen from the example. Hence i'd mark this as answer. I cant use iFrame version of like button since I have to track it using the app id, the developer says its just not possible to use the iframe version.

Comment: What do you need to track exactly?  The amount of likes?  If so, why not just add another fb:like button, and set `width: 0;` and `height: 0;` and every so many seconds check it for more likes, and if their are more likes, than do whatever you need to do.

Comment: yeah, i've explored that option aswell in past. But somehow the developer doesn't agree with it. So, i'd leave it as it is for now.

Comment: Have you tried the top answer on this stackoverflow question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up

Comment: Also, try changing `send=false` I'm sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: yes, that was probably the first thing i tried when I came across this problem. But anyways, thanks for the answer and follow up through the comments. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the comment box class via code analysis and apply Solomon Closson's CSS answer to remove it from page display.

Something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .like-btn-comment-box { display: none !important; }
</style>
```

Where `.like-btn-comment-box` is the comment box class

Comment: Yeah, if you can get the comment box class and just apply it to the head, that would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: But that class is inside the iframe, and AFAIK, its not possible to fiddle with contents of an iframe which is loaded from a different domain. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's right, now the last idea I have, is to apply a complete hide on the button, add your own button (copy the image) and a javascript action onclick that clicks on the hidden button, is that understandable?

Comment: hide the `iframe` than... use `display: none;` on the actual iframe, unless the button is being displayed in the `iframe` as well...?