# How to remove "comment box" from facebook box_count?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I would like to remove the "comment box" after I click "like button".

I have box_count and I use this code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="..." data-width="450" data-layout="box_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

I saw [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up), but doesn't work.

How can I remove the comments from box count? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this css override

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget iframe.fb_ltr {
     display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: It works for button_count, but doesn't work for box_count...
I have already this code in my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  #fb-container {
    height: 20px !important;
    width: 93px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;      
  }
</style>

<div id="fb-container">
    <div id="fb-root">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/youraddr" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</div>
```