# Hide Facebook comment popup when like on mobile viewport?

Tags: css, facebook

I meet this issue on mobile viewport only.The Facebook Like button create a pop-up when user hit it, the problem is on mobile viewport the width isn't enough and the pop-up is being cut off. I want to hide it and I followed the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247855/facebook-like-button-how-to-disable-comment-pop-up) but it take me to another problem:[image: Facebook like pop-up display inside like button].

This problem should be handled by css is the best solution, I can't handle more on html and javascript.

Comment: u need to handle it from js is what you meant?or this css is not working?

Comment: I need to handle this issue with css only, not with html of javascript

Comment: what was the issue with u using that css which is mentioned in that answer?

Comment: the pop-up existed inside the div that contain the like button, as you see on my image